# Refresh view on android

Tags: android, android-view

I have a class that inherits from view. (Basically it draws a shape). In my main activity have a button.
When I click the button create a new class which inherit from View, and that way I draw new shape. But on my screen any changes happened.

Here is the my button click event;

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        mView.invalidate();
        mView = new MyPen(getBaseContext(), null);
        mView.SetValueOlcu(tvOlcu.getText().toString());
        frmLayout.addView(mView,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        frmLayout.refreshDrawableState();
        frmLayout.buildLayer();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    

    }
});
```

*I used `refreshDrawableState();` but nothing changes.How can I update my view which reflect the last changes on screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you using mView.invalidate() as the first command in onClick and just before a new MyPen object creation? It doesn't make any sense. You should use an invalidate command when your view already drawen in your layout and has some changes to redraw it. Maybe something wrong with your view visualization? What does your MyPen do?

Comment: as I when the screen first loaded ,I have already draw a shaped

Comment: I drow an regtangular,when clcik the button It add new line on this regtengular

Comment: I mean MyPen draw a regtangular

Comment: I think the main reason why you don't see any changes on your screen is your MyPen view object sizes. First, when you're creating your view with wrap_content attributes you don't pass this attributes to the parent in your constructor method. And second, i think you need to override onMeasure method to let your view know how much space it should take. Or you can set your view sizes more precisely. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: nope I set pricese heigh and width but ,nothing changes idemigod

Comment: I have also edit text on my screen ,when I clcik edit text,I can see the changes

Comment: Excuse me, but where exactly did you set height and width?
Have you tried to use invalidate as the last parameter in onClick?

Comment: both button clcik event and xml file ,